# Excel VBA: cannot Get inner text of HTML id

Tags: html, excel, vba

Hi: I'm using excel to get values from this webpage: https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/es13/h/iexmmmfi.html

How can I get the code for excel VBA to get the fiels for NIF, EJF, MOD and CEL?

I tried with getelementbyid("NIF") and "name" but with no results

Thanks!

Previos thread: [Excel VBA: Get inner text of HTML table td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205442/excel-vba-get-inner-text-of-html-table-td)

This is the code I use:

```
Sub AEAT()
  Dim IE As Object
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.Navigate "https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/es13/h/iexmmmfi.html"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


  IE.Document.getElementById("NIF").Value = Range("A1").Value
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

  IE.Document.getElementById("EJF").Value = "2016"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

  IE.Document.getElementById("MOD").Value = "347"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

  IE.Document.getElementById("CEL").Value = Range("a4").Value
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

  IE.Document.getElementById("env_button").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Post the code you have used

Comment: Code added. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem may be more fundamental. Try opening the browser with this URL, open the console (usually by pressing F12) and write `document.getElementById('NIF')`. Do you get some kind of result? Once you can successfully use the DOM outside of VBA, converting the code within VBA is relatively trivial.

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest including the HTML you are trying to parse. In my case, I am running a browser without Java, and so cannot see the webpage you are trying to parse.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie, so I don't have a Excel in Windows VM, so I tested your code using VBScript. So the solution should work. You have 3 problems

1. Navigate doesn't wait for Page for to load
2. Your site installs a ActiveX control, which needs to be loaded first
3. Even when you fix #1 and #2, you will get an exception "The client disconnected" and the object will not be usable anymore

**Solution**

Add the site to Trusted Sites in your IE Setting.

[image: IE Settings]

Open IE manually and install the ActiveX control

```
Sub AEAT()
  Dim IE
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.visible = True
  hwnd = ie.hwnd
  IE.Navigate "https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/es13/h/iexmmmfi.html"
  msgbox ("wait")

  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
         If hwnd = Wnd.hwnd Then Set ie = Wnd
  Next 
  IE.Document.getElementById("NIF").Value = "123"
End Sub

Call AEAT
```

I have put msgbox to insert wait for now, but you can fix that yourself by using below in excel

```
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

PS: reference from below URLs

[Internet Explorer VBA Automation Error: The object Invoked has disconnected from its clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403210/internet-explorer-vba-automation-error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from)

[Error "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" - automate IE 8 with python and win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661005/error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients-automate-ie-8-wit)

Comment: Great! Imany thanks! But i still have a problem with the field "MOD" or "ID_MOD", it doesn't work neither by using get elementbyID or byname.

Comment: MOD only has name so you need to use GetElementsByName, which returns an array not a object. So you need to use `document.getElementsByName("MOD")[0].value = "038"`

Comment: Sorry, it returns me "syntax error" in excel VBA. getElementsByName("MOD")[0]

Comment: Excel VBA Code:Sub AEATWEB()


  Dim IE
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  Hwnd = IE.Hwnd
  IE.Navigate "https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/es13/h/iexmmmfi.html"
  MsgBox ("wait")
  
  
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  

  For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
         If Hwnd = Wnd.Hwnd Then Set IE = Wnd
  Next
  
  IE.Document.getElementById("EJF").Value = Range("A2").Value
  
  IE.Document.getElementsByName("MOD")[0].value = "347"
  
 
  
  
End Sub

Comment: Get the value in to another variable first and then use index on it

Comment: `Set MOD = IE.Document.getElementsByName("MOD")` and `MOD[0].value = "347"`

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems not working... or I don't know how to complete the vba code correctly. Help!

Comment: after writing the code "set MOD = IE.document........." in VBA module  apears error: Identifier expected

Comment: Use `IE.Document.getElementsByName("MOD").Item(0).value = "347"`